# tablesorter - hide multiple tables based on filter of one column

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter, dropdownbox

I am using jquery tablesorter to filter tables. Now I am trying to select a value from an external dropdown and based on that value to hide one or multiple tables. The code should search in the hidden column "Team". If the value is not found in this column the table should "hide".

The tables are created by a mysql query and php. These are the table header.

```
echo "<table class='tablesorter' id='".$lid."' style='width:80%'>
<thead>
<tr>            
    <th colspan='2'><a href='league.php?lid=".$lid."'>".$getlid['LEA']."</a></th>
    <th class='num_caption' title='Spiele'>Sp</th>
    <th class='num_caption'  title='Siege'>S</th>
    <th class='num_caption'  title='Niederlagen'>N</th>
    <th class='num_caption'  title='Wertungspunkte'>WP</th>
    <th class='num_caption'  colspan='2' title='Korbpunkte'>Punkte</th>         
    <th class='num_caption'  title='Differenz Korbpunkte'>Dif</th>                          
    <th class='num_caption'  title='Spiele verloren mit Spielwertung'>Wert</th>     
    <th style='display:none';>Team</th>
</tr>
</thead>";
```

This seem to be more complex then I thought.Is there a way to do it with tablesorter or is the best way to have my own functions? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3690/)):

CSS

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<select class="search" data-column="0">
    <option></option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>

<table>...</table>
<table>...</table>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('table')
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
            widgetOptions: {
                filter_external: '.search'
            }
        })
        .on('filterEnd', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('hidden', this.config.filteredRows === 0);
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi Mottie, your answer is what I am looking for. One additional question: I dont want the the table (or tables) that remain to be filtered. I want to hide the entire table or show the table with all rows. What do I need to change?